# How do I make table of images with text over each image in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, web

I'm making a website, and I have to make a panel of images, with a text over each one of them. I made a `<table>`, but when I added up `<p>` to every image, they became one column instead of a table.

Making `<p>`'s position absolute doesn't help at all.

How can I link every `<p>` to the middle of the image while saving table position?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use table and not divs, then try something like this - this will center the text over each image in each table cell:

```
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table >
<td class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
  </td>

  <td class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
  </td>

    <td class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
  </td>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you:) But that way table still works as one column, and all text is located directly in the center, in 1 place, but I have 5 images and I need to center the text on each one of them

Comment: in my example there are 3 columns, each with 1 image and centered text. Do you mean you want 5 images in 1 table cell? Any screenshot or example what exactly you want to achieve could be helpful

Comment: The guy im making the site for, want a table of images-links. Like, 3-4 columns with 2 rows of images. Here is my stupid drawing of what I'm trying to do :D 
https://imgbbb.com/image/LXSibc
I did all the <table> things, but images are still just one column

Comment: Okay, I've made a <div> container instead of <td> one, and it worked great. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: yes, that was my code in original, but I replaced it with table as you wanted table :) Glad that it works. You can accept my answer if you find it helpful